# How to turn an intel wifi card into AP under Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking

I have an intel wifi card using iwlwifi driver. I want to turn it into an AP (not only an ad-hoc) so that my phone can share its wired network.

I've searched the internet (including superuser.com), finding things like hostapd. Since iwlwifi does not support master mode. Hostapd doesn't work at all.

However, a program on Windows 7 called [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com) successfully turn my card into AP.
So I believe this is also possible on Linux. However, I have not found any solutions yet.

Does any one know how to turn a wifi card without master mode into an AP, under Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: I tried for somes weeks to do this but it seems with iwlwifi drivers is not possible.
See this link:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint
for now my android can see the net with wifi radar but not connect

Comment: This has nothing to do with the iwlwifi driver: I have an Intel centrino card with iwlwifi; I can create an AP, sending all the connection requests from the wireless clients to the internet via a bridge with my ethernet card, or create a bridge with a virtual interface on the same card, so that all communication goes thru my wireless card. In other words, it acts simultaneously as a client to a pre-existing wifi network, and an access point sending packets to the pre-existing network. If you tell me which configuration you are interested in, I will post the relevant details.

Comment: You may want to list what kernel, what Intel Centrino Wi-Fi firmware, what version of hostapd you're using.

Comment: The output of `iw phy` is also useful. Supported interface modes should include `AP`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu you can connect your computer to LAN first then go to the wireless menu in the top bar. Then press Create network or Create hotspot then you can choose SSID and WEP password.